# Integrating with roots in the integrand

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the best way to deal with an integral with a root or roots in the integrand? For example, given the following problem what would be the best strategy to use to proceed? $$\int\frac{w}{w-2\sqrt{6-3w}-5}dw$$I am thinking maybe a $u$-substitution, but is there another way that is more efficient or easier?

Comment: As already commented, getting rid of the radical is the first thing to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ x=2-w, dw=-dx$

$$\int {w \over w -2\sqrt{6-3w} -5}dw =\int {2-x \over (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt3)^2} dx$$

Let $\large v={1 \over \sqrt{x} + \sqrt3 },\; dv =\large({-1 \over 2\sqrt x})({1\over (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt3)^2})dx$

Let $u = 2(x-2)\sqrt{x}$, do integration by parts

$$\int u dv = u v - \int v du = {2(x-2)\sqrt x \over \sqrt{x} + \sqrt3} + 6\sqrt{3x} - 3x - 14\log(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt3)$$

Substitute back $x=2-w$, and drop the constant of integration, we get:

$${-2w\sqrt{2-w} \over \sqrt{2-w} + \sqrt3} 
+ 6\sqrt{6-3w} + 3w - 14\log(\sqrt{2-w} + \sqrt3)$$